# Python package cx_Oracle==5.1.3 Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required for

Tags: python, c++, jenkins

Trying to install cx_Oracle==5.1.3 package onto windows 2012 server Through Jenkins. Using python 2.7 with setuptools-41.1.0.dist-info. I have installed Microsoft C++ Compiler for Python 9.0 but pip complains it can't find it

Run the pip install code from the command line and it works. Tried setting various paths, tried calling the C++ environment from Jenkins. Scoured the internet for advice, not getting anywhere :(

call "C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64

%WORKON_HOME%\emileTest\Scripts\pip install cx_Oracle==5.1.3

This is the Jenkins error log

> Collecting cx_Oracle==5.1.3
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/25/afc07a79ed268f6ab2e8959cfcff997504ce09500b881a1d93f92904762e/cx_Oracle-5.1.3.tar.gz
>
> Building wheels for collected packages: cx-Oracle
>
> Building wheel for cx-Oracle (setup.py): started
>
> Building wheel for cx-Oracle (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>
> command: 'c:\envs\emiletest\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\windows\temp\pip-install-umf517\cx-Oracle\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'c:\windows\temp\pip-install-umf517\cx-Oracle\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'c:\windows\temp\pip-wheel-kg80iv' --python-tag cp27
>          cwd: c:\windows\temp\pip-install-umf517\cx-Oracle\
>
> Complete output (5 lines):
>     running bdist_wheel
>
> running build
>
> running build_ext
>
> building 'cx_Oracle' extension
>
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Comment: Can we convince you to upgrade to something released in the last 5 years?

Comment: Ha! Obvious solution, the issue is the company I work for have to ensure their products can work on a host of legacy applications and OS.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this build problem with Jenkins, what I did is install the old cx_Oracle version under the default python site packages. I use virtualenv so I can create a virtual environment and basically tell it to inherit the default python site packages like this:

```
mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages env_name
```

So this environment will have access to the default cx_Oracle package. Since the requirement will already be satisfied, pip will not try to install it again when building in Jenkins.

I would love to upgrade a lot of things but it's just not seen as priority as long as everything works.